# HTML/PHP Form: only some names works

Tags: php, html, post

I have this html form here:

```
<form action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" id="addTip" method = "POST">
            Título: <input type = "text" name = "title" />
            Tipo:   <input type = "text" name = "type"  />
            Data:   <input type = "text" name = "data"  />
            Imagem: <input type = "text" name = "image" />
                    <input type = "submit"              />
        </form>

        <textarea name="comment" form="addTip">Enter text here...</textarea>
```

and I call it on a php file like this:

```
if($_REQUEST["title"] || $_REQUEST["type"] || $_REQUEST["data"] || $_REQUEST["image"]){...}
```

The html code is below the php one, so the code above is all in 1 page.

When I open the file, the REQUEST returns an error saying that every `<input>` has undefined index, except type and image.

If i change the names of image and type, those `<input>` don't work either.

If I change the names back again to image and type the code works and if I only use those as `$_REQUEST`, my php code works well.

Why I'm having this behaviour?

Comment: Another `isset` duplicate?

Comment: @JonStirling Closed. :)

Comment: try to use `if($_POST["title"] || $_POST["type"] || $_POST["data"] || $_POST["image"]){...}` instead

Comment: @JonStirling I want to know why some work and some don't, so it's not a duplicated.